# Looking for Design Resources to Practice HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking to find some resources to help me practice my HTML and CSS coding. I'm not having much luck, so I thought I'd post. I'm looking for a website that gives a design mockup, maybe even the image files, and then work it it into functional HTML, CSS, JS and so on; something with code examples to compare with would be great.

If anybody knows of a website like this, I would love to know. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this three links to start

http://www.w3schools.com/ good resource for html and css

http://css-tricks.com/ realy good resource for css learning

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css

and of course youtube tutorials are my best option for beginers

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqvFIuVlyP8&list=PL41lfR-6DnOruqMacTfff1zrEcqtmm7Fv
[https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=html5+css3+javascript](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=html5%20css3%20javascript)

Comment: Hi, thanks for providing the instructional materials, though I'm not really looking for CSS/HTML lessons. I appreciate you taking the time though.

Comment: you can find severals psd to start coding in http://freebiesbug.com/psd-freebies/website-template/

Comment: This is pretty cool, It looks like there's definitely a fair amount PSD mockups to work with. I think I've even seen some cool "coding challenges" on Reddit too. I would love a community site that combines it all together, but this would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of free psd templates around internet. You can slice them and make your own web site. 
Also I recommend online courses like teamtreehouse.com they have online tools to validate your code after lessons. Not full website design but they are always testing your knowledge after each lesson.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this will help with at least collecting some of the materials. I realize a lot of coders work from a design markup, so I'm trying to practice from that perspective. I think it would be great to have a site where a design is submitted and the challenge is to attempt to convert it to code. It would be a nice way to see how others approach the challenge.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/
It lets you practice by entering code and seeing the results right away

Comment: Hi there, I like w3schools, but it's not really what I'm looking for.